# React Child Component Is Not Rerendering When Props Are Updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My parent component takes input from a form and the state changes when the value goes out of focus via onBlur.

```
useEffect(() => {
    let duplicate = false;

    const findHierarchy = () => {
      duplicationSearchParam
        .filter(
          (object, index) =>
            index ===
            duplicationSearchParam.findIndex(
              (obj) => JSON.stringify(obj.name) === JSON.stringify(object.name)
            )
        )
        .map((element) => {
          DuplicateChecker(element.name).then((data) => {
            if (data.status > 200) {
              element.hierarchy = [];
            } else {
              element.hierarchy = data;
            }
          });
          if (duplicate) {
          } else {
            duplicate = element?.hierarchy?.length !== 0;
          }
        });
      return duplicate;
    };

    let dupe = findHierarchy();
    if (dupe) {
      setConfirmationProps({
        retrievedData: formData,
        duplicate: true,
        responseHierarchy: [...duplicationSearchParam],
      });
    } else {
      setConfirmationProps({
        retrievedData: formData,
        duplicate: false,
        responseHierarchy: [],
      });
    }
  }, [duplicationSearchParam]);
```

I have a child component also uses a useeffect hook to check for any state changes of the **confirmationProps** prop.

the issue is that the event gets triggered onblur, and if the user clicks on the next button. this function gets processes

```
 const next = (data) => {
if (inProgress === true) {
  return;
}
inProgress = true;
let countryLabels = [];
formData.addresses?.map((address) => {
  fetch(`/api/ref/country/${address?.country}`)
    .then((data) => {
      countryLabels.push(data.label);
      return countryLabels;
    })
    .then((countries) => {
      let clean = MapCleanse(data, countries);

      fetch("/api/v1/organization/cleanse", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(clean),
      })
        .then((data) => {
          if (data.status > 200) {
            console.log(data.message);
            message.error(getErrorCode(data.message.toString()));
          } else {
            Promise.all([confirmationProps, duplicationSearchParam]).then(
              (values) => {
                console.log(values);

                console.log(data);
                setCleansed(data);
                **setCurrent(current + 1);**
                inProgress = false;
              }
            );
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
          inProgress = false;
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      inProgress = false;
    });
});

console.log(confirmationProps);
```

};

The important part in the above code snippet is the setCurrent(current + 1) as this is what directs our code to render the child component

in the child component, i have a use effect hook that is watching [props.duplicateData.responseHierarchy]

I do output the values of props.duplicateData.responsehierarchy to the console to see if the updated information gets passed to the child component and it does. the values are present.

I have a conditional render statement that looks like this

```
 {cleansedTree?.length > 0 || treeDuplicate ? (...)}
```

so although the data is present and is processed and massaged in the child component. it still will not re render or display properly. unless the user goes back to the previous screen and proceeds to the next screen again... which forces a re-render of the child component.

I have boiled it down and am assuming that the conditional rendering of the HTML is to blame. Or maybe when the promise resolves and the state gets set for the confirmation props that the data somehow gets lost or the useefect doesn't pick it up.

I have tried the useefect dependency array to contain the props object itself and other properties that arent directly related

UPDATE: this is a code snippet of the processing that gets done in the childs useeffect

```
useEffect(() => {
console.log(props.duplicate);
console.log(props.duplicateData);
console.log(props.confirmationProps);
let newArray = props.duplicateData.filter((value) => value);

let duplicateCheck = newArray.map((checker) =>
  checker?.hierarchy?.find((Qstring) =>
    Qstring?.highlightedId?.includes(UUIDToString(props?.rawEdit?.id))
  )
);

duplicateCheck = duplicateCheck.filter((value) => value);

console.log(newArray, "new array");
console.log(duplicateCheck, "duplicate check");

if (newArray?.length > 0 && duplicateCheck?.length === 0) {
  let list = [];

  newArray.map((dupeData) => {
    if (dupeData !== []) {
      let clean = dupeData.hierarchy?.filter(
        (hierarchy) => !hierarchy.queryString
      );
      let queryParam = dupeData.hierarchy?.filter(
        (hierarchy) => hierarchy.queryString
      );

      setSelectedKeys([queryParam?.[0]?.highlightedId]);

      let treeNode = {};
      if (clean?.length > 0) {
        console.log("clean", clean);
        Object.keys(clean).map(function (key) {
          treeNode = buildDuplicate(clean[key]);

          list.push(treeNode);
          return list;
        });

        setCleansedTree([...list]);
        setTreeDuplicate(true);
      } else {
        setTreeDuplicate(false);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

}, [props.duplicateData.responseHierarchy]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with this problem was that the state was getting set before the promise was resolved. to solve this issue I added a promise.all function inside of my map and then proceeded to set the state.

What was confusing me was that in the console it was displaying the data as it should. but in fact, as I learned, the console isn't as reliable as you think. if someone runs into a similar issue make sure to console the object by getting the keys. this will return the true state of the object, and solve a lot of headache

Answer (score 0):

This is a decently complex bit of code to noodle through, but you did say that `**setCurrent(current + 1);**` is quite important. This pattern isn't effectively handling state the way you think it is...

`setCurrent(prevCurrent => prevCurrent + 1)`

if you did this

```
(count === 3)
setCount(count + 1) 4
setCount(count + 1) 4
setCount(count + 1) 4
```

You'd think you'd be manipulating count 3 times, but you wouldn't.

Not saying this is your answer, but this is a quick test to see if anything changes.

Comment: oh current just holds a value of 1 or 2, its directly taken from antd's component examples. the state is not to continually increase but basically to either hold 1 or 2